# R - ordered factor over multiple columns

Tags: r, factoring

I'm pretty brand new to R, so please excuse any R grammer errors here...

I have a 19 question likert survey saved in a data frame (19 columns). The responses are numeric and converted to characters.

I would like to change the Likert scores to factor and specify levels. I can do this with each column individually, but wondering how to use a loop to apply this to all columns without having to repeat this line of code 19 times for all columns

My current code

```
lik_tab$lik_01 <- factor(lik_tab$lik_01,
                          levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                            ordered = TRUE)
```

I know I can repeat that for the next columns "lik_02", lik_03"... and so on, but how do I write this more succinctly?

I tried lapply with the following error:

```
lik_tab <- lapply(lik_tab,factor(levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
+                                      ordered = TRUE))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'factor(levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), ordered = TRUE)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If we wrap with the function call, use anonymous function, also while assigning to the full dataset, use `[]` to keep the structure of the dataset, otherwise, it would be a `list` output from the `lapply`

```
lik_tab[] <- lapply(lik_tab, function(x) factor(x, 
                   levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                  ordered = TRUE))
```

Otherwise, we can just specify the parameters

```
lik_tab[] <- lapply(lik_tab, factor, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                   ordered = TRUE)
```

Comment: akrun's answer is great. I needed to convert a subset of factor columns to the ordered factors. I used `dataset[ordered_vars] <- apply(dataset[ordered_vars], 2, as.ordered)`. However, it converted the factors to characters. Then, I used `dataset[ordered_vars] <- lapply(dataset[ordered_vars], as.ordered)`. I was able to convert the `ordered_vars` to ordered factors. Thanks

Comment: @MehmetYildirim the second option with `lapply` works because `apply` converts data.frame to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single class.  It would coerce it to `character` and remove the factor attributes